# Pydub audio export has silence at the start?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, pydub

I wrote a python script to take audio in 30 minute mp3's and slice it into unix timestamped, second long files. The source audio files are 192kbps, 441000Hz, stero mp3 files.

I want it that way for a service that archives audio from a radio station (where I work) and can deliver it to a user over a given start and end time, to the second. We had the server shut down for an hour for maintenance (we try not to but it happens) and we recorded it over that time using a different computer that saved our audio in 30-minute chunks. Normally this archive server saves the second-long chunks itself without issue.

The function that does the conversion, given a 30 minute input audio file, the directory to save the output chunks in, and the start time of the file as a unix timestamp:

```
def slice_file( infile, workingdir, start ):
    #find the duration of the input clip in millliseconds
    duration_in_milliseconds = len(infile)

    print ("Converting " + working_file + "  (", end="", flush=True)

    song = infile
    #grab each one second slice and save it from the first second to the last whole second in the file
    for i in range(0,duration_in_milliseconds,1*one_second):
        #get the folder where this second goes:
        arr = datefolderfromtimestamp( int(start) + (int(i/1000)))
        #print ("Second number: %s \n" % (int(i/1000)) )
        offset = (i + one_second)
        current_second = song[i:offset]
        ensure_dir(working_directory + "/" + arr[0] + "/" + arr[1] + "/" + arr[2] + "/")
        filename = os.path.normpath(working_directory + "/" + arr[0] + "/" + arr[1] + "/" + arr[2] + "/" + str(int(start) + (int(i/1000))) + "-second.mp3")
        current_second.export(filename, format="mp3")

        #indicate some sort of progress is happening by printing a dot every three minutes processed
        if( i % (3*60*one_second) == 0 ):
            print ('.', end="",  flush=True)

    print (")")
```

My issue is that all the second files converted by this script seem to be longer than a second with on average 70 ms of silence at the start of them. When I download files from my archiver server it gives me all the files concatenated together, so it sounds terrible and glitchy.

Can someone help me out? I'm not sure where this error is coming from.

My full script if you're curious:

http://pastebin.com/fy8EkVSz

Comment: Here's what my bad audio sounds like. Note that it's supposed to be 2 minutes long, but is instead 2:07 due to all the small silences adding up due to the concatenation of 120 second-long files: http://www.citr.ca/?attachment_id=69907

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Found out the source of this - LAME adds buffers to the start of the file.

See: http://lame.sourceforge.net/tech-FAQ.txt